# Keycloak port-forward from local kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am trying to connect Keycloak running on local Kubernetes cluster with Spring Security OAuth application. When I port-forward Keycloak from k8s using `kubectl port-forward svc/keycloak 8080:8080` I can access web GUI with no problem, but when Authorizing with Spring Security, it will always throw an error

```
Invalid token issuer. Expected 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master', but was 'http://10.104.81.255:8080/auth/realms/master'
```

Here is my Keycloak configuration in Spring

```
keycloak:
  realm: master
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  ssl-required: external
  resource: my-resource
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  public-client: true
```

Please let me know how I can set this up, so I can continue developing locally.

**NOTE**: When the Spring Application runs within the cluster and I port-forward that one instead, it obviously works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't configured the `frontendUrl` for the [Hostname provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/15.0/server_installation/#_hostname). Set it to `http://localhost:8080/auth` and you should be fine.